# How to add a request interceptor to a feign client?

Tags: java, spring, authentication, header, feign

I want every time when I make a request through feign client, to set a specific header with my authenticated user.

This is my filter from which I get the authentication and set it to the spring security context:

```
@EnableEurekaClient
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients
public class PerformanceApplication {
    @Bean
    public Filter requestDetailsFilter() {
        return new RequestDetailsFilter();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PerformanceApplication.class, args);
    }

    private class RequestDetailsFilter implements Filter {
        @Override
        public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

        }

        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            String userName = ((HttpServletRequest)servletRequest).getHeader("Z-User-Details");
            String pass = ((HttpServletRequest)servletRequest).getHeader("X-User-Details");
            if (pass != null)
                pass = decrypt(pass);
            SecurityContext secure = new SecurityContextImpl();
            org.springframework.security.core.Authentication token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userName, pass);
            secure. setAuthentication(token);
            SecurityContextHolder.setContext(secure);
            filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        }

        @Override
        public void destroy() {

        }
    }
    private String decrypt(String str) {
        try {
            Cipher dcipher = new NullCipher();

            // Decode base64 to get bytes
            byte[] dec = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(str);

            // Decrypt
            byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(dec);

            // Decode using utf-8
            return new String(utf8, "UTF8");
        } catch (javax.crypto.BadPaddingException e) {
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is my feign client:

```
@FeignClient("holiday-client")
public interface EmailClient {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/email/send", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    void sendEmail(@RequestBody Email email);
}
```

And here I have a request interceptor:

```
@Component
public class FeignRequestInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {
    private String headerValue;

    public FeignRequestInterceptor() {
    }

    public FeignRequestInterceptor(String username, String password) {
        this(username, password, ISO_8859_1);
    }

    public FeignRequestInterceptor(String username, String password, Charset charset) {
        checkNotNull(username, "username");
        checkNotNull(password, "password");
        this.headerValue = "Basic " + base64encode((username + ":" + password).getBytes(charset));
    }

    private static String base64encode(byte[] bytes) {
        BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
        return encoder.encode(bytes);
    }

    @Override
    public void apply(RequestTemplate requestTemplate) {
        requestTemplate.header("Authorization", headerValue);
    }
}
```

I don't know how to configure this interceptor to my client and how to set the header with the username and password. How can I accomplish that ?

Answer (score 23):

You don't really need your own implementation of the `FeignRequestInterceptor` as there is already [BasicAuthRequestInterceptor](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/master/core/src/main/java/feign/auth/BasicAuthRequestInterceptor.java) in the `feign.auth` package that does exactly the same.

That being said, you basically have almost everything set up already. All is left to do is to define the `basicAuthRequestInterceptor` bean with specific username and password:

```
@Bean
public RequestInterceptor basicAuthRequestInterceptor() {
    return new BasicAuthRequestInterceptor("username", "password");
}
```

Comment: Is there possible to add @Qualifier for RequestInterceptor  @Bean?

Comment: Sure it's possible. But Feign is not aware of custom qualifiers. If you need to switch between RequestInterceptors you need to introduce some custom Feign Configuration.

Answer (score 7):

I know the thread is a bit old but wanted to give some explanation on what's happening here.

If you'd like to customize your Feign requests, you can use a `RequestInterceptor`. This can be a custom implementation or you can reuse what's available in the Feign library, e.g. `BasicAuthRequestInterceptor`.

How to register it? Well, there 2 ways to do it depending on how you use Feign.

If you're using plain Feign without Spring, then you gotta set the interceptor to the Feign builder. An example is [here](https://github.com/galovics/mastering-feign-practice/blob/regular-feign/online-store-service/src/main/java/com/arnoldgalovics/online/store/service/external/config/FeignConfiguration.java).

```
Feign.builder()
     .requestInterceptor(new MyCustomInterceptor())
     .target(MyClient.class, "http://localhost:8081");
```

If you're using Spring Cloud OpenFeign and you use the `@FeignClient` annotation to construct your clients, then you have to create a bean from your `RequestInterceptor` by either defining it as a `@Component` or as a `@Bean` in one of your `@Configuration` classes. Example [here](https://github.com/galovics/mastering-feign-practice/blob/spring-feign/online-store-service/src/main/java/com/arnoldgalovics/online/store/service/external/config/SourceRequestInterceptor.java).

```
@Component
public class MyCustomInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {
    @Override
    public void apply(RequestTemplate template) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Also, you can check out one of my articles in this topic, maybe that clears it up better: [Customizing each request with Spring Cloud Feign](https://arnoldgalovics.com/feign-interceptor/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=post&utm_campaign=customizing-each-request-with-spring-cloud-feign)

Comment: I'm using Spring Cloud OpenFeign, with the @FeignClient annotations. Is there a way to only add the request interceptor to a specific feign client, or is the only way to do that to use Feign.builder().requestInterceptor ?

Comment: @BoomShaka The @FeignClient annotation gives you a `configuration` attribute where you can specify which configuration class you want to be picked up for that particular feign client. In your case, create a configuration class with the request interceptor defined as a Spring Bean and apply that configuration in the @FeignClient annotation where you need it.

Comment: Awesome, good job. Cheers mate.