# Java Spring - intercepting execution of a REST Client (Hystrix Feign)

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, hystrix

I have a REST client interface like this:

```
public interface NameSearchClient {
    @RequestLine("POST")
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    SearchResponse searchByName(NameSearchRequest request);

}
```

It gets implemented and set-up in a factory class like this:

```
@Component
public class NameClientFactory {
    public <T> T createFeignClient(Class<T> clientClass, String apiUrl) {
        return Feign.builder()
                .encoder(new GsonEncoder())
                .decoder(new GsonDecoder())
                .target(clientClass, apiUrl);
    }
}
```

I was wondering if it's possible to write an Aspect annotation that upon every call made by that client, executes some action (another HTTP call in my case) and adds a new header to the request? Is AspectJ the right tool for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a bean that implements `feign.RequestInterceptor` and do your work in there:

```
@Component
public class FeignRequestInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {
  @Override
  public void apply(RequestTemplate template) {
    // your code here
  }
}
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40262132/how-to-add-a-request-interceptor-to-a-feign-client).